# Как вывести размер папки из терминала в Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, linux

Как вывести размер папки из терминала в Ubuntu?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Получить размер папки можно с помощью команды `du`.

Команда.

```
du -h --max-depth=1 | grep папка
```

Вывод.

```
158M    ./папка
```

Answer (score 24):

`du -h -s /full/path/to/folder/`

Пример вывода для папки с вложенными папками:

669M    idea-IC-162.1812.17

Comment: В текущей директории можно просто `du -hs .`

Answer (score 14):

Можно еще проще

```
du -h <имя-директории>
```